# How to obfuscate FXML so that it refers to the obfuscated Controller classes?

Tags: javafx, proguard, obfuscation, fxml

I am obfuscating JavaFX application. FXML file refers to its corresponding controller classes. I don't want to hard code the controller names in the FXML's inside the obfuscated jar because I have so many controllers and I cannot find all the classes every time I obfuscate. Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just encapsulate it into an inner controller:

1. Create one controller that is initialized from the fxml file with
   the required methods to manage that screen
2. then modify all of the other controllers to initialize that controller and this way there will be only one fxml file, but all of the controllers can use that inner controller to build their screen.

You just need to create a factory to hide the initalization, I made a spring bean based controllerfactory for this.